# Bash Script, CD Into A Directory With A Dynamic Name

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script and need to cd into a directory, but the directory name is somewhat dynamic. It always begins with package-{then dynamic version}. How do I script this in bash?

`cd package-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I get your requirement fully.

What about `cd package-*`? If there are several matches, which one would you like to choose?

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one such directory in that directory, you could do

```
cd package-*
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, however it would break if you have more than one folder..

```
#!/bin/bash

find . -type d -name package* -exec cd {} \;
Do something else
```

Comment: I really doubt you can change dir that way